# Leaving and coming back while still eating

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

There is a halacha that a change of location necessitates a new beracha.  However, if one is in the middle of eating something while they change location, they can finish that item without making a new beracha. For example, if you are eating a bag of potato chips, and you leave the building where you made your beracha, you can continue eating the bag of potato chips as you travel.

If someone left and came back to the same original location, while eating their bag of potato chips, do they need to make a new beracha when they come back?

In other words, is the beracha that they made terminated once they left, but the same act of eating is still a residual inclusion in the beracha (in which case a new beracha would be necessary when they came back), or is the beracha still in effect as long as they are still eating the same item, and the beracha is not terminated until they finish (in which case if they return to the same place before they finish their original beracha may still be in effect)?

Comment: "if one is in the middle of eating something while they change location, they can finish that item without making a new beracha" Can you provide a source for this?